# How to run simple node.js Hello World program in linux dedicated server

Tags: javascript, php, linux, node.js

I am quite new to node.js programming.  I am using linux dedicated server. I already have installed node.js in my server(linux).

I am using follwing php program to run the linux command so i can run node.js program by these linux command

**test.php:**

```
exec('node test.js &', $a1,$a2);
print_r($a1);
echo $a2;
```

And after running this program it showing following o/p:

```
Array ( ) 0
```

But not returns any value in $a1 variable where it should display "Hello World"

**test.js:**

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I also tried with port 3000 and 8000.

Comment: why you are running nodejs with php script?

Comment: what gives you `var_dump(function_exists('pcntl_fork'));` ?

Comment: where's the part that talks to the node http server and catches the response?

Comment: My project has such requirement. Actually I want presentation application, there will be a controller and n no of users at the same slide (say 10k or above). any other suggestions?

Comment: @dandavis:As I said I am new to nodejs. The same code runs on my local machine (Windows OS) but not on server(Linux)

Answer (score 3):

For once I cannot see how the same code runs on Windows, but not on Linux. Especially since your php contains UNIX syntax.

Please do not use PHP as a bridge to Node.js, it just kills all the point of having Node.js in first place.

---

What you need to do is run a command in the Shell of that linux machine:

```
node test.js
```

It will start a process, do not exit it.

Once the process is running, you shall be able to navigate to your `Hello World` through a browser, the URL will be based on your Server's IP and port you chosen, example:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8888/
```

If that does not answer your question, then clarify please, on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I did it on linux local server and it worked. But I need to get it run on linux dedicated hosting server where I cannot access shell.
Is there any other way to run it via PHP?

I am developing a live presentation web application (something like presentation.io), presentor will control the slides and users will be on the same slide. I read node.js can do this job. Let me know if there is any other option.

Please advise.

Comment: How did you install node.js without shell access?

Comment: It installed by linux server tech-support team.

Comment: If I run follwing php program then it gives o/p as: – Array ( [0] => Hello World ) 0 (It mean this Hello World program is running successfully)
**PHP Program:**
exec('node test.js &', $a1,$a2);
print_r($a1);
echo $a2;

**test.js program**
console.log("Hello World");